# I have a tall page with a modal that is displayed within a very tall iframe. How can I position the modal so that it is on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, scroll

I'm using the Bootstrap modal on many buttons on the page. If I scroll down the page and click a button, naturally the modal will open visibly at the top of the window (not the document). All is well.

However, I want to be able to support the same functionality within very tall iframes. Let's say an iframe is 1000px tall. If I scroll down the top level document to say, halfway down the iframe, but I did not scroll the contents of the iframe at all, I'm running into an issue. If I click a button, the javascript thinks no scrolling has been done, and renders the modal at the top of the iframe document. Thus the modal is not on screen (I have to scroll the top-level document up in order to see it).

Assuming that the parent window and iframe contents are on different domains (so same origin policy applies), is there any way for me to detect where to position the modal so that it's always viewable without scrolling the parent or iframe documents?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet. Modal will we shown 60px bellow the top edge of user's viewport. And if content of modal is taller, than user's screen he will be able just to scroll the page to see it. But modal should have `position: absolute`

```
$("#showPopup").click(function() {
    var posX = 60 + $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#popupToShow")
        .css({top: posX} )
        .fadeIn(150);
});
```

Comment: Nope, sorry. Within the iframe `window` actually refers to the same document within the iframe. So when I scroll down the outside page, window.offsetTop is still 0 -- it hasn't changed.